Using struct field values within an Arc-wrapped method gives "move occurs because self has type Arc<T>, which does not implement copy"
I have a process that receives data from a tokio oneshot::channel, and then uses it in conjunction with some self struct fields, however, my access to the struct fields seems to be unallowed even when wrapping it in an Arc. Trying to understand how to achieve this successfully:
use anyhow::{Error, Result};
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};
use tokio::sync::oneshot::{self, Sender, Receiver};
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Task {
    some_data: String,
    some_other_data: String,
}

impl Task {
    pub fn new(some_data: String, some_other_data: String) -> Self {
        Self {some_data, some_other_data} 
    }

    pub async fn do_stuff(self: Arc<Task>) -> Result<(), Error> {

        // spawn task with a self method
        let (tx, rx): (Sender<String>, Receiver<String>) = oneshot::channel();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            self.do_more_stuff(tx).await.unwrap_or_else(|err| {
                println!("ERROR: {err}");
            });
        });

        match rx.await {
            Ok(data) => {
                // using self fields here results in error
                println!("{}, {} took: {}", self.some_data.clone(), self.some_other_data.clone(), data)
            }
            Err(_) => {
                panic!();
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    pub async fn do_more_stuff(self: Arc<Task>, tx: Sender<String>) -> Result<(), Error> {

        let sleep_time = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..3);
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(sleep_time)).await;


        // send on channel
        if let Err(_) = tx.send(sleep_time.to_string()) {
            panic!();
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {

    let data_one = String::from("hello");
    let data_two = String::from("world");

    // spawn some tasks
    let mut handles = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..5 {
        let t = Arc::new(Task::new(data_one.clone(), data_two.clone()));
        handles.push(
            tokio::spawn(async move { t.do_stuff().await })
        );
    }

    futures::future::join_all(handles).await;
    Ok(())
}


Cargo.Toml
[dependencies]
anyhow = "1.0.82"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
futures = "0.3.30"
rand = "0.8"

[dependencies.tokio-util]
version = "0.6"
features = ["compat"]

EDIT: Added compiler error:
(main) bash > cargo check
    Checking arc_testing v0.1.0 (C:\Users\me\rust_sandbox\arc_testing)
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `self`
    --> src\main.rs:30:45
     |
18   |       pub async fn do_stuff(self: Arc<Task>) -> Result<(), Error> {
     |                             ---- move occurs because `self` has type `Arc<Task>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
22   |           tokio::spawn(async move {
     |  ______________________-
23   | |             self.do_more_stuff(tx).await.unwrap_or_else(|err| {
     | |             ---- variable moved due to use in coroutine
24   | |                 println!("ERROR: {err}");
25   | |             });
26   | |         });
     | |_________- value moved here
...
30   |                   println!("{}, {} took: {}", self.some_data.clone(), self.some_other_data.clone(), data)
     |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
     |
     = note: borrow occurs due to deref coercion to `Task`
note: deref defined here
    --> C:\Users\me\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\alloc\src\sync.rs:2054:5
     |
2054 |     type Target = T;
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^
help: clone the value to increment its reference count
     |
26   |         }.clone());
     |          ++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `arc_testing` (bin "arc_testing") due to 1 previous error


Can you please add the complete error message from the compiler (cargo check) not your IDE as formatted text

@cafce25 added.

Just clone self.

@ChayimFriedman Where? I don't see how that will work and I've tried cloning prior to using the struct field within the match arm

let this = self.clone(); before the spawn and use this instead of self inside spawn().

@ChayimFriedman is this standard practice for this type of pattern?

Like do I have to clone prior to spawning something in a tokio::spawn() as general usage?

If you want to use it after, yes. This is an Arc so it's cheap to clone.

Thanks. It just increments the ref count under the hood? Isn't actually copying the entire struct and fields therein?

@Coldchain9 It just increments the ref count under the hood? - correct. Being able to do such (cheap) cloning is the whole point of using an Arc.
